# How to save on solder paste usage on the SMT line?

Tags: solder-paste

We are using about 500g of solder (enough to scan solder) on 1 line and only reuse it for the 2nd time (cannot use the 3rd time) and then discard the used solder.
The problem is that the amount of destruction is very large when summarizing the date (about 3/4 of the original volume), is there any way to save this amount of solder?

Comment: Is it being refrigerated? What's causing you to be unable to use it a 3rd time? Expiry dates? Unacceptable yield?

Comment: I'm pretty sure when I print to the 3rd time the efficiency is only about 70% (tested by us). And it's cooled before first unwrapping, then not.

Comment: Well, not refrigerating during storage after opening it would be large reason why yields are unacceptably low after enough time has passed. How long is it sitting from the start of the 1st run to the start of the third run?